# Sublime Text 2 FileTemplates plugin doesn't work

Tags: templates, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to use "FileTemplates" plugin in Sublime Text 2. I installed it with Package Controller, but when I use "Create file from template" and select something, nothing happens! It doesn't even create a file.

How can I make it work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find you current user's packages folder. Here you will find where the FileTemplates package has been installed. On my Windows system it is %APPDATA%\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\FileTemplates. You may also get to this folder from the Preferences menu by selecting Browse Packages...

Inside this folder there is a Templates folder. Inside this folder you will find the pre-canned file templates. You may create your own by copying and pasting the existing files to create the templates you like. You will need to create a .file-template file in the FileTemplates folder. This file is an xml file which tells sublime where to find the actual template and what parameters to the file creation the user may pass into the template. For instance $name is the parameter that the user is prompted for which will be used to name the file created from the template. Hope this helps.